# What is the purpose of y_pos in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been browsing the documentation for matplot lib, but I don't understand the purpose of `y_pos`. For example, why can't I use `fullnames` instead of `y_pos`?

```
def CreateScoreBarChart(subject):
    #Get all the names and  scores for that subject
    GetScoresSQL="""SELECT firstname,secondname,score FROM students WHERE subject=%s"""
    mycursor.execute(GetScoresSQL,(subject,))
    myresults = mycursor.fetchall()
    fullnames = []
    scores = []
    for person in myresults:
        fullname=person[0]+" "+person[1]
        fullnames.append(fullname)
        scores.append(person[2])
    y_pos = sorted(fullnames)
    plt.bar(y_pos, scores, align='center', alpha=0.5,color=['b'])
    plt.xticks(y_pos, fullnames)
    plt.ylabel('Score')
    plt.xlabel('Full Name')
    plt.title(subject+"'s Class Scores")
    plt.show()
```

**Sample Data**

```
#Function to populate database
def RandomStudentMaker(NoOfStudents):
    studentFNames = ["Alex","Brad","Diane","Jimmy","Logan","Harry","Susan","Olivia","Beth","Amy","Charles","Megan","Gareth","Tony"]
    studentSNames=["Gaston","Leslie","Copeland","Smith","Dill","Brown","Rowan","Austin","Harley","Eakin","Colgan","Fry","Cook","Laurie"]
    subjectNames=["Chemistry","Biology","Computer Science"]
    insertStudentSQL="INSERT INTO students (firstname,secondname,subject,score) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"

    for i in range(0,NoOfStudents):
        print("here")
        mycursor.execute(insertStudentSQL,(random.choice(studentFNames),random.choice(studentSNames),random.choice(subjectNames),random.randint(0,100)))
        mydb.commit()
RandomStudentMaker(20)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that would allow us to see what you're seeing, and play with the code?

Comment: @Roy2012 sure I have done so, I just want clarity on why I need to make a y_pos variable

Comment: Have you tried just using `fullnames` instead of `y_pos`? I don't think it throws error.

Comment: There's nothing that prevents you from using full names.In fact, using y-pos leads to a bug - the order of names is not aligned to the order of scores.

Comment: @Roy2012 your second assertion is not true, as `bar` will take `y_pos` as just *a sequence of length N* according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Comment: you're using y_pos as the first argument to plt.bar. This is the x-axis in this case. If you're changing the order of the values for x (by sorting), but not for y - your chart will be wrong.

Comment: No error occurs when I remove and replace ypos with fullnames, but I don't understand this line plt.xticks(fullnames, fullnames), why is fullnames passed twice?

Comment: @Roy2012 In OP's case the values of `y_pos` is not scalar, so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: isn't fullnames a list of names, as in ["John Smith", "Jane Doe", "Mark Twain"]?

Comment: @Roy2012 yes it is

Comment: so ... if you sort it, and now it's Jane before John, the correlation of Jane's score (100%, second in the scores list) to Jane's bar (now first in the list) would be messed up. Won't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played a bit with your code. Your question, in a way, is more about the use of x-ticks: which isn't necessary in your case.

Assume we have four students with the corresponding scores:

```
[('Beth', 'Harley', 60),
 ('Olivia', 'Dill', 69),
 ('Megan', 'Harley', 48),
 ('Charles', 'Laurie', 43)]
```

The relevant three lines in your code are:

```
# fullname = ['Beth Harley', 'Olivia Dill', 'Megan Harley', 'Charles Laurie']

y_pos = sorted(fullnames)
# y_pos = ['Beth Harley', 'Charles Laurie', 'Megan Harley', 'Olivia Dill']

# at this point, the order of items in y_pos doesn't match the order of 
# items in scores
plt.bar(y_pos, scores, align='center', alpha=0.5,color=['b'])

# here, you're rearranging the labels on the x-axis to match the right order 
# of students
plt.xticks(y_pos, fullnames)
```

A simpler solution would be not to sort the names in the first place, and just let matplotlib do its thing.

```
plt.bar(fullnames, scores, align='center', alpha=0.5,color=['b'])
#  This line is deleted ==> plt.xticks(y_pos, fullnames)
```

The result is the same:

[image]